# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY Error in Approval Process

Tags: apex, approval-process

Following error is popped up when trying to approve the approval step by code.I can sense this error is because of wrong work item id but I am unable to do so.

**Approval Process error:**

> System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []:

Apex Class:

```
public void approveRecord(SLA_Claim__c opp)
{
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
req.setComments('Approving request using Trigger');
req.setAction('Approve');        
//req.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {});  I don't need this as requirement is only for last step to approve via code.      
ProcessInstanceWorkitem workItem =[Select Id,ActorId from ProcessInstanceWorkitem  where ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId =: Opp.ID AND ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'];

if(workItem.Id == null)
{
opp.addError('Error Occured in Trigger');
}
else
{
req.setWorkitemId(workItem.Id);
// Submit the request for approval
Approval.ProcessResult result =  Approval.process(req);
}
}
```

Comment: Is that record submitted for approval? Here is a good example to [approve record using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process_example.htm).

Comment: Yes Submitted .I had gone through the example which you linked above before writing my class.